# ManyToMany bidirectional with cascade, save works on one side (owning side) but not the other

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

When I persist the Question (with Tag added to the array) using the QuestionRepository, the corresponding tag is saved automatically, along with the row in `question_tag` Table, but when I save the Tag (with the question added to its Question array) using tag repository, nothing happens, I added the Cascade to the other side as well, the question is created but nothing in the  `question_tag` Table.

```
//Tag Entity
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
private List<Question> questions;

//QuestionEntity
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "question_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
)
private List<Tag> tags;

//Saving the Tag entity
Tag tag = tagRepository.findById(1L).get();
Question q = new Question();
q.setTitle("tryme44");
q.setTxt("ttttttrrrrryyyyb");
tag.addQuestion(q);
tagRepository.save(tag);
```